# How does ARM(or other processors) unwind stack at ISR return?

Tags: arm, interrupt

In normal function return, the compiler knows the size of the stack and it can adjust the size of the stack based on the local arguments and no of parameters passed but in the case of nested ISRs, there is no way for the compiler to know how much stack needs unwinding? How does it work? Does the frame pointer play a role here?

Comment: Generally, each ISR knows how much stack it allocated and releases that before it returns (just like a normal function return).  With nested ISRs, the inner one will restore its stack and return to the outer one which will restore its stack before also returning.

Comment: Yeah, it's not any different.  The ISR is only unwinding its *own* stack, whose size it knows just as for any other function.  Maybe you are thinking that it is also trying to unwind the stack of the interrupted code (which could itself be an ISR), but that wouldn't make sense - the whole point of an interrupt is to occur transparently and leave the interrupted code, and its data, untouched.  If it was unprivileged code that was interrupted, then the (privileged) interrupt handler uses an entirely separate stack altogether.

Comment: I think that makes sense. If each ISR has to unwind its own stack, then it knows the size and can also save the return address for the nested ISR calls.

Comment: nothing magic or special about an isr.  other than often the psr is saved as well as the return address and a special instruction is used to restore both rather than a normal return that only deals with return address.  Otherwise stack usage is stack usage, the compiler or human has to get it right per "function"...you dont get it right then with or without an interrupt the train goes off the rails....

Comment: some you have to save the psr yourself (some dont have a psr/flags) and the extremely rare case like the cortex-m the logic preserves most/all of the state for you (Except what the calling convention, if observed, already does (compiler))

Comment: What particular ARM are you asking about?  ARM64, Cortex-R, Cortex-A, Cortex-M or historical ARM.  They have different answers to your question.  Cortex-A and historical ARM CPUs have banked 'SP' and 'LR' per mode.  These are used to address the issues you note there.  For the Cortex-M, the CPU uses the normal stack and may do lazy saves of FP registers depending on configuration.  Also, it may depend on whether you have pre-emptive interrupts enabled or not on complete mechanics as well as TrustZone, and the interrupt controller.